# connect to VM Ubuntu from win cmd on the same machine

Tags: 14.04, command-line, oracle

I have Ubuntu installed on a virtual machine on my windows computer. Instead of starting Ubuntu from Oracle on the same machine. I am wondering if there is a way to start and connect via windows command line. I do not need a Ubuntu graphical interface. What I need is only connection to the terminal.

Comment: Well something has to run the virtual machine so you have to start it in oracle. Than you can `sudo apt install openssh-server` on the Ubuntu and use e.g. PuTTY on Windows in order to connect to the terminal via SSH. (of course they have to be in the same network etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try out Vagrant, simply download Vagrant and Virtualbox and you can then spin up an Ubuntu VM with no GUI in 4 simple steps:

1. mkdir ubuntu-vm
2. cd ubuntu-vm
3. vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64 # Create the Vagrantfile and specify the image to use in one command
4. vagrant up && vagrant ssh # Start up the VM and connect to it via SSH

Obviously remove the comments I put in from #

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see my dekstop or home folder! and I did not enter my username and password

Comment: What do you mean? If you connect to a Virtual machine its a different environment and has its own file system.